# Plot no consecutive days with even intervals

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using the following function to plot a graph showing 2 months figures per year for 6 years

```
def plot_report(property_type, first_period, year_periods, month_periods):
    reporting_periods = get_reporting_periods(first_period, year_periods, month_periods)
    data = get_rows(df, property_type, reporting_periods)
    suburbs = data.groupby(['state', 'suburb'])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    for i, suburb in suburbs:
        suburb.plot(x='yrend', y='median_price', ax=ax, linewidth=2)

    ax.xaxis.set_ticks(reporting_periods)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%b %y"))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

    ax.grid(False)
    ax.legend().set_visible(False)
    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    locs, labels = plt.xticks()
    plt.setp(labels, rotation=90)

    return plt.show()
```

Whereas *reporting_periods* might return

```
[datetime.datetime(2004, 12, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2005, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2003, 12, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2004, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2002, 12, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2003, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2001, 12, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0)]
```

This is the resulting graph:
[image]

How do I distribute dates on the x-axis evenly - with the same interval?

Some sample data:

```
suburb  state   house   yrend   median_price
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/01/91 0:00   91000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   28/02/91 0:00   90000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/03/91 0:00   92000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/04/91 0:00   92000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/05/91 0:00   92400
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/06/91 0:00   94000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/07/91 0:00   95000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/08/91 0:00   95000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/09/91 0:00   96000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/10/91 0:00   97100
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/11/91 0:00   98000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/12/91 0:00   98000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/01/92 0:00   103000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   29/02/92 0:00   105000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/03/92 0:00   106000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/04/92 0:00   109000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/05/92 0:00   110000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/06/92 0:00   113975
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/07/92 0:00   117000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/08/92 0:00   118000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/09/92 0:00   119725
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/10/92 0:00   120000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/11/92 0:00   123250
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/12/92 0:00   123250
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/01/93 0:00   123500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   28/02/93 0:00   123500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/03/93 0:00   123500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/04/93 0:00   125000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/05/93 0:00   123500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/06/93 0:00   123000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/07/93 0:00   120000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/08/93 0:00   120000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/09/93 0:00   120000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/10/93 0:00   120000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/11/93 0:00   118500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/12/93 0:00   118500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/01/94 0:00   118200
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   28/02/94 0:00   119000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/03/94 0:00   118500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/04/94 0:00   118500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/05/94 0:00   118200
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/06/94 0:00   119500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/07/94 0:00   119500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/08/94 0:00   119500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/09/94 0:00   118850
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/10/94 0:00   119500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/11/94 0:00   116500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/12/94 0:00   116000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/01/95 0:00   115000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   28/02/95 0:00   112250
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/03/95 0:00   110000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/04/95 0:00   110000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/05/95 0:00   109975
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/06/95 0:00   106000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/07/95 0:00   106000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/08/95 0:00   106000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/09/95 0:00   104000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/10/95 0:00   103500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/11/95 0:00   101000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/12/95 0:00   101750
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/01/96 0:00   102750
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   29/02/96 0:00   103000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/03/96 0:00   100500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/04/96 0:00   100000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/05/96 0:00   99500
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/06/96 0:00   98750
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/07/96 0:00   96000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/08/96 0:00   97000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/09/96 0:00   98750
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/10/96 0:00   98750
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   30/11/96 0:00   100000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/12/96 0:00   98000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/01/91 0:00   381000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   28/02/91 0:00   382325
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/03/91 0:00   382000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/04/91 0:00   385000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/05/91 0:00   382650
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/06/91 0:00   381325
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/07/91 0:00   389000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/08/91 0:00   388500
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/09/91 0:00   383825
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/10/91 0:00   381325
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/11/91 0:00   379000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/12/91 0:00   374500
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/01/92 0:00   371000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   29/02/92 0:00   371000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/03/92 0:00   370700
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/04/92 0:00   370000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/05/92 0:00   370200
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/06/92 0:00   370000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/07/92 0:00   365000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/08/92 0:00   370000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/09/92 0:00   373750
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/10/92 0:00   375000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/11/92 0:00   380000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/12/92 0:00   381000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/01/93 0:00   388000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   28/02/93 0:00   384000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/03/93 0:00   389000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/04/93 0:00   395000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/05/93 0:00   397500
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/06/93 0:00   400000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/07/93 0:00   400000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/08/93 0:00   397500
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/09/93 0:00   400800
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/10/93 0:00   405000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/11/93 0:00   406500
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/12/93 0:00   122500
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/01/94 0:00   122000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   28/02/94 0:00   125000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/03/94 0:00   125000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/04/94 0:00   125000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/05/94 0:00   126750
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/06/94 0:00   129975
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/07/94 0:00   133725
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/08/94 0:00   137000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/09/94 0:00   140000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/10/94 0:00   142750
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/11/94 0:00   142750
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/12/94 0:00   149000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/01/95 0:00   157000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   28/02/95 0:00   160000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/03/95 0:00   161875
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/04/95 0:00   165000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/05/95 0:00   165000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/06/95 0:00   171500
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/07/95 0:00   179000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/08/95 0:00   185000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/09/95 0:00   189950
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/10/95 0:00   195000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/11/95 0:00   195500
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/12/95 0:00   198000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/01/96 0:00   206000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   29/02/96 0:00   210000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/03/96 0:00   211500
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/04/96 0:00   219000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/05/96 0:00   225000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/06/96 0:00   234000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/07/96 0:00   245000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/08/96 0:00   245500
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/09/96 0:00   247000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/10/96 0:00   248000
BELCONNEN   ACT H   30/11/96 0:00   249500
BELCONNEN   ACT H   31/12/96 0:00   248000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/01/91 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   28/02/91 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/03/91 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/04/91 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/05/91 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/06/91 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/07/91 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/08/91 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/09/91 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/10/91 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/11/91 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/12/91 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/01/92 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   29/02/92 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/03/92 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/04/92 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/05/92 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/06/92 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/07/92 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/08/92 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/09/92 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/10/92 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/11/92 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/12/92 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/01/93 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   28/02/93 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/03/93 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/04/93 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/05/93 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/06/93 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/07/93 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/08/93 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/09/93 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/10/93 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/11/93 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/12/93 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/01/94 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   28/02/94 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   31/03/94 0:00   405900
BRUCE   ACT H   30/04/94 0:00   339000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/05/94 0:00   360000
BRUCE   ACT H   30/06/94 0:00   377500
BRUCE   ACT H   31/07/94 0:00   377500
BRUCE   ACT H   31/08/94 0:00   377500
BRUCE   ACT H   30/09/94 0:00   377500
BRUCE   ACT H   31/10/94 0:00   360000
BRUCE   ACT H   30/11/94 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/12/94 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/01/95 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   28/02/95 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/03/95 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   30/04/95 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/05/95 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   30/06/95 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/07/95 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/08/95 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   30/09/95 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/10/95 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   30/11/95 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/12/95 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/01/96 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   29/02/96 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/03/96 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   30/04/96 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/05/96 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   30/06/96 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/07/96 0:00   351000
BRUCE   ACT H   31/08/96 0:00   302750
BRUCE   ACT H   30/09/96 0:00   307750
BRUCE   ACT H   31/10/96 0:00   312000
BRUCE   ACT H   30/11/96 0:00   312000
```

Comment: I think we'll need some example data to figure this out. A small example dataframe would be great. Without example data, the only thing I can suggest is removing the `x='yrend'` arg from your plot calls, so `suburb.plot(y='median_price', ax=ax, linewidth=2)`. That should result in data points just being spaced evenly along the axis.

Comment: It looks like you are explicitly telling it to use non-uniform dates via the ` ax.xaxis.set_ticks(reporting_periods)` so mpl is behaving correctly.

Comment: @Marius, Just added some example data to the question - note, there are more columns in the CSV

Comment: @tcaswell, thanks for your comment. I do know it is behaving correctly. The question is how to draw it with non consecutive dates.

Comment: Just omitting that line doesn't do what you want?

Comment: @tcaswell, if I remove that line it shows the ticks as the pic attached above, but only one month per year. It basically removes Dec 99, Dec 00, Dec 01, etc. It only keeps the Januarys

Comment: You want the month locator: http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

table = """suburb  state   house   yrend   median_price
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   31/01/91 0:00   91000
CHARNWOOD   ACT H   28/02/91 0:00   90000
...
BRUCE   ACT H   30/11/96 0:00   312000
"""

table = table.replace("0:00", "")
sio = StringIO(table)
df = pd.read_table(sio, sep=r"\s+", parse_dates=['yrend'])
df = df.pivot(index="yrend", columns="suburb", values="median_price")
df.plot()
```

[image]

what you really need here reshaping with pivot http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html.

**EDIT:** to tune the formatter, might not exactly what you need, but you got the idea. to such fine grind customization, you have to resort to matplotlib ...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter, NullFormatter
import pylab

from StringIO import StringIO

table = table.replace("0:00", "")
sio = StringIO(table)
df = pd.read_table(sio, sep=r"\s+", parse_dates=['yrend'])
df = df.pivot_table(index=["yrend"], columns=["state","suburb"], values=["median_price"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot the lines
for col in df.columns:
    ax.plot(df.index, df[col])

# tune the tickers 
locator  = dates.MonthLocator(range(1, 13), bymonthday=1, interval=6)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(locator)
def _monthFmt(x, pos):
    dt = pylab.num2date(x)
    return dt.strftime('%Y') if dt.month == 2 else dt.strftime("%b")
formatter = FuncFormatter(_monthFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(formatter)
# quiet major formatter - default the years
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="minor")

ax.yaxis.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dyno for pointing me to Reshaping and Pivot Tables - I didn't know the later was supported by Pandas. 

It seems to work fine as longs as there **is not** repeated suburb names across different states. Which is not the case - that's way I was grouping by state and suburb in my function. 

suburbs = data.groupby(['state', 'suburb'])

How do you do this grouping in a pivoted table?

Comment: I've the way to do it:   
`pivoted = pd.pivot_table(df, index='yrend', columns=['state', 'suburb'], values='median_price')`  
Using pivot_table rather than pivot. I'm using Pandas 0.15.2

Comment: I've managed to create the pivot table, however, I'm still struggling to show the labels on x-axis correctly. I tried `pivoted = pd.pivot_table(data, index='yrend', columns=['state', 'suburb'], values='median_price')
 pivoted.plot()
 plt.xticks(np.arange(len(reporting_periods)), reporting_periods, rotation=90)`

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a DateFormatter (as you already do), I would suggest to use a [DateLocator](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateLocator) (in your case a YearLocator makes sense) to position the ticks (instead of positioning them manually with `ax.xaxis.set_ticks`):

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())
```